# Python - Combining Multiple CSV Files Renders Text Field as Number

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python script to combine multiple CSV files. I am using data hosted in a GitHub repository here: https://github.com/statistikat/coronaDAT

The script works well and combines the multiple CSV files. However it take the first column, which is text, and renders it as numbers.

**Any suggestions on why the merged CSV is changing the first column from text to numbers?**

**Original CSV File:** 
[image: Original CSV File]

**Merged CSV File:**
[image: Merged CSV File]

Here is my Python script:

```
import glob

path = r'/Users/matt/test/' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)

    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
#export to csva
frame.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't render the text as numbers - it ignores the values from first column, because you specified during concatanation, that it should be ignored. Then it shifts all the columns by 1.

If you want to see the city names, you should leave out the parameter `ignore_index=True`.

So, instead of:

```
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

There should be:

```
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=False)
```

or simply

```
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0)
```

Secondly, when you create the resulting CSV file, you tell it to ignore the indexes - even with correct frame, you would still receive first column with numbers.
You should change:

```
frame.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

to:

```
frame.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It did as suggested. I also had to specify the delimiter as ";" for it to work properly as the original file was putting the ;-separated data in different columns. I changed the pd.read_csv line as such ```df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';', header=0, index_col=['Timestamp','GKZ'], parse_dates=['Timestamp'])```